# Rollup measures using Calculated Members - SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap-cube

I have an SSAS cube and in it I have a default measure of distinct count on a column in my fact table.
On top of this default measure I have a calculated measure that's filtering out the columnid = 1 values from being counted.
This calculated measure works fine until we start using dimensions to start aggregating up and down the calculated measure.This is not a problem when using the default measure.
This is the MDX for the calculated measure that I am using,
    `distinctcount(existing CROSSJOIN(Except([DimensionA].[Id].[Id], [DimensionA].[Id].&[1]),[Measures].[Dimension A Count]))`
Please provide your feedback on how can I achieve rolling up and down with a calculated measure.

Thanks & Regards,
Syed

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to do as far as "aggregating up and down the calculated measure"? Using the calculated measure what value are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In the client application, when I use the calculated measure in the report, I get correct value in the report. But when I bring in multiple dimensions the value doesn't break down by different members in the dimension.
For example, if I have product count in the report, then I can group that count by different categories but in addition to categories if I bring in location dimension, the measure isn't grouped correctly.

Comment: Is this information sufficient or do I need to provide additional details?
I think that the MDX in the calculated field needs to be updated but I am not able to figure that out.

Comment: any input here please?

Comment: Is the underlying measure used in the calculated measure actually connected in the dimension usage tab to all of the dimensions you are using in the query you are running?

Comment: Hi mmarie,
Sorry for the delayed response. Yes my underlying measure is connected to all the dimensions in the dimension usage tab.
All the respective dimension keys are connected to the underlying measure in the usage table

Comment: any input on this please?
Thanks